# how to measure ac motor with AC ammeter

Tags: capacitor, motor, ac, amperage

I have 3 different working motors ranging from 1kw to 2 kw (on 220V AC, 1 phase), they all use running capacitors.
I tried 2 different AC ammeters on them and I get bad readings between 0 to 1 amp, when I should read at least 5 amps.

I cant figure out what's going on, but I guess it has to do with the running capacitors, in one instance when the motor has the running capacitor disconnected ( and therefore the motor cant spin) I get a realistic 6 amp reading.

So do you know what's messing up the AC amp readings and how could I measure the amps that the motors use ?

Comment: Are the motors fully loaded? If not then you will not measure the 5A or 10A that you expect. A motor draws current proportional to the mechanical load that is on it.

Comment: if the motor was running unloaded, 1A sounds about right.

Comment: the motor wasnt loaded, after applying a bit of load manually the amp needle rised a bit, thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: fully loading these motors is difficult, isnt there another way to calc their amperage/ power ?

Comment: You can not determine the rated current for motors that do not have a nameplate (rating plate) or other documentation. The best you can do is estimate from the motor's physical size and operating speed along with catalog data for similar motors.

Comment: Without some kind of LOAD on the motor, "their amperage/ power " is UNDEFINED. That makes no sense. The "amperage/ power" DEPENDS on how much is the load on the motor.  You are asking an impossible question.  Like "How much does a box weigh?" without knowing what is INSIDE it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The motor should be loaded in order to measure it's amperage.